# What's the difference between CentOS 6 and CentOS 7

Tags: centos

Does anyone know what's the big difference between CentOS 6 and CentOS 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big-ticket changes are listed in [the CentOS 7 (1406) release notes](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7.1406):

> - Kernel updated to 3.10.0
> - Support for Linux Containers
> - Open VMware Tools and 3D graphics drivers out of the box
> - OpenJDK-7 as default JDK
> - In Place Upgrade from 6.5 to 7.0 (as already mentioned)
> - LVM-snapshots with ext4 and XFS
> - Switch to systemd, firewalld and GRUB2
> - XFS as default file system
> - iSCSI and FCoE in kernel space
> - Support for PTPv2
> - Support for 40G Ethernet Cards
> - Supports installations in UEFI Secure Boot mode on compatible hardware

The release notes link to [the corresponding RHEL release notes](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/part-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7.0_Release_Notes-New_Features.html) which provide much more information, and to [the migration guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/index.html) which lists all the potential gotchas, including deprecated and remove packages, and removed drivers. You should also check [the release notes for subsequent versions of CentOS 7](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes) since you should install the latest release in the 7 family (1804 as of this writing).

Answer (score 0):

Distributions are very different from the OSX and Windows ecosystems. Distributions get a bunch of packages to work together, and work out which ones conflict, so that users do not have to do it themselves. As such, "what's the difference" is a large group of patches, commits, and choices made by the maintainers. What each user is interested in varies, but usually the things quoted are kernel version, init script version, and any major libraries and programs (glibc, gcc, etc).

CentOS doesn't have Debian's carefully maintained and extensive wiki on package versions. If you are interested in a specific package, check which version the two distributions are at, and look through the changelogs of the upstream software.

EDIT:
Centos does have release notes, as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472792/210567) states, but this is only a list of what the maintainers think is important. A package may have deprecated a rarely used feature that you need, or added a piece of functionality that will shave hours off your workflow.

Comment: The RHEL release notes (which cover CentOS) do have exhaustive lists of replaced, deprecated, and removed packages, and deprecated and removed drivers.

Comment: @StephenKitt I shall update my answer.

Comment: Also, if the “extensive wiki on package versions” is [what I think it is](https://packages.debian.org), it’s not a wiki ;-). RHEL has an equivalent, which is accessible to users with subscriptions (including the free developer subscription), but I don’t know whether CentOS does.

Comment: @StephenKitt I was referring to the mixture of packages.debian.org and wiki.debian.org that describe the packages in great detail. After searching through the interwebs, many sources agreed that there was no equivalent to debian/ubuntu/RHELs wiki.